# PDF String Extract a checkbox being checked or not

Tags: pdfbox

We have a method to check if a checkbox in a PDF (No forms) is checked or not and it works great on one company's PDF. But on another, there is no way to tell if the checkbox is checked or not.

Here is the code that works on one company's PDF

```
 protected static final String[] HOLLOW_CHECKBOX = {"\uF06F", "\u0086"};
 protected static final String[] FILLED_CHECKBOX = {"\uF06E", "\u0084"};

 protected boolean isBoxChecked(String boxLabel, String content) {
    content = content.trim();
    for (String checkCharacter : FILLED_CHECKBOX) {
        String option = String.format("%s %s", checkCharacter, boxLabel);
        String option2 = String.format("%s%s", checkCharacter, boxLabel);
        if (content.contains(option) || content.contains("\u0084  ") || content.contains(option2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, when I do the same for another company's PDF there is nothing in the extracted text near the checkbox to tell us if it is checked or not.

The big issue is we have no XML Schema, no Metadata, and no forms on these PDFs, it is just raw String, so you can see a checkbox is difficult to have in a String, but that is all we have. Here is code example of pulling the String in the PDF from a page to some other page, all the text in between

```
protected String getTextFromPages(int startPage, int endPage, PDDocument document) throws IOException {
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    stripper.setStartPage(startPage);
    stripper.setEndPage(endPage);
    return stripper.getText(document);
}
```

I wish the pdfs had an easier way to extract the text/data, but these vendors that make the PDFs decided it was better to keep that out of them.

No we cannot have the vendor's/ other companies change anything, we receive these PDFs from the courts system that have been submitted by lawyers that we don't know and that the lawyers bought the PDF software that generates these files.

We also cannot do it the even longer way of trying to figure out the object model that PDFBox creates of the document with things like

```
o.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine - processing substream token: PDFOperator{Tf}
```

because these are 80-100 page PDFs and would take us years just to code to parse one vendor's format.

Comment: There are many many ways one can put something into a pdf that looks like a check box. Thus, unless you provide a representative sample document to analyse, there is no way to help you here.

Comment: mkl, thanks for the response, This is another vendor's PDF and the data in the PDF is sensitive data, so have no way to post anything. It is something that the Lawyers is allowed to "fill out" but we do not get a Form in the PDF at all. So I would suspect it is just a normal checkbox, not an image.

Comment: Maybe the checkbox isn't at the place you expect it? There is a sort option for the stripper.

Comment: Thanks for the response. They are not our lawyers (as stated in the question in other ways "No we cannot have the vendor's/ other companies change anything, we receive these PDFs from the courts system that have been submitted by lawyers that we don't know..."). 

There are hundreds of lawyers that use this other vendor (Not us) PDF that they fill out to file with the courts. It is 10000% out of our hands, we just receive an email with a PDF from the courts. We just get the PDF as is and we have to parse it to get data for our own application.

Comment: Thanks Tilman, I will see if that can help. This PDF does seem to come out Top to bottom then left to right, rather than a line being left to right.

Comment: In the worst case, you'll have to render the PDF and use OCR. TIKA (which uses PDFBox) has this as an option.

Comment: Tilman Thanks again for the reply. When you say render the PDF, I don't understand what you mean, we get the PDF in a link in an email that the court system mails us. We go to the link and download the PDF, then we use PDFBox to extract the text in the PDF, and this is where I get the checkbox and its text, but there is no Unicode character there to show if it is checked or now, We have another PDF vendor that does have a Unicode character that tells us, but not with this other vendor's PDF files.

Comment: @user1567291 render means convert to image. If there is no text, it could be that the font used by the creator of that PDF does not have unicode assigned to it. It's not uncommon that PDF files are flawed.

Comment: I have tried to OCR the PDF but the results still have nothing for the checkboxes in it. I was hoping it might be able to convert an image Checkbox into Text or some representation of the checkbox and it being empty or checked. ;( And now the districts have required that the posters scan the pages that have signatures such that those pages are now just scanned images and no PDF/Text to extract.